# Downloading only one page of a table in pdf using jsPDF-AutoTable

Tags: javascript, pdf, jspdf-autotable

I want to download a pdf file of a table contents.For this I am using jsPDF-AutoTable library.But when I download the file it is downloading only one page.My code is below.Please tell me,what should I change in my code?

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.2/jspdf.min.js"</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf-autotable/2.3.2/jspdf.plugin.autotable.js"></script>
<script>
function download_pdf(val) {
    if (val == 3) {
       var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt');
       var elem = document.getElementById("myTable");
       var res = doc.autoTableHtmlToJson(elem);
       doc.autoTable(res.columns, res.data,{ 
       styles: {overflow: 'linebreak'},
       columnStyles: {
       0: {columnWidth: 50}, 
       1:{columnWidth:50}, 
       2: {columnWidth: 50}, 
       3: {columnWidth: 40},
       4: {columnWidth: 40}, 
       5:{columnWidth:40}, 
       6: {columnWidth: 40}, 
       7: {columnWidth: 40},
       8: {columnWidth: 40}, 
       9:{columnWidth:40}, 
       10: {columnWidth: 40}, 
       11: {columnWidth: 40},
       12: {columnWidth: 40}
       }
       });
       doc.save("can_data_report.pdf");
   }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Looks good to me! Are you seeing any errors? Does it work if you test removing your custom styles?

Comment: I am not getting any errors.Yes,it is working if I remove custom styles. But I need my custom styles in my project.

Comment: Which style breaks it?

Comment: <?php if($download==3){}else{?>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/jquery.dataTables.css">

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script> <?php } ?>

Comment: Without including those files it works? Which file is causing the issue?

Comment: yes,one is css style sheet and another is javascript file

Comment: Which file is causing the issue?